# DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8-15530' failed to install

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dnx

I cloned a repository based on ASP.NET 5 Mvc 6 Beta 8.
Visual Studio could not install the latest DNX SDK.

This is the error message:
"DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta8-15530' failed to install. The solution will use DNX SDK version 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta7' for this session.

I tried to run dnvm upgrade but it said I already have the latest version.

This is the repository: https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Odachi/tree/master/src/Odachi.Security.BasicAuthentication (It is a sample for Middleware implementing basic authentication).

Is it possible that this code uses some beta build which is not yet available for the dnvm?

**Update**

```
C:\Windows\system32>dnvm upgrade -u
Determining latest version
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-15798 from https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2
Installing to C:\Users\mjost\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-15798
Adding C:\Users\mjost\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-15798\bin to process PATH
Adding C:\Users\mjost\.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-15798\bin to user PATH
Updating alias 'default' to 'dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-15798'
```

Does not seem to do what is expected. I got the same error message when I open the solution after executing `dnvm upgrade -u`

**It still does not compile. How to install that exact dnx needed?**

**Update**
I updated to the stable beta 8 and still got errors. I posted an issue in the original Github repository: https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Odachi/issues/4

Comment: What version of `dnvm` are you using?

Comment: dnvm version 1.0.0-beta8-15516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNVM uses `aspnetdev` as unstable feed which contains RC1 builds now and the stable NuGet feed contains beta7 builds. You can set the feed to `aspnetrelease` temporarily and then run the upgrade:

```
SET DNX_FEED=https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/
dnvm upgrade
```

This will install `v1.0.0-beta8-15794`.

---

**Update:** another option would be to remove the `version` (and the `sdk`) element of the [global.json](https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Odachi/blob/master/global.json). With this option you force .NET to build your app against the specified runtime, which you don't want. If you don't specify it, it will build against the current active runtime.

Comment: Is it not possible to install just "dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-15798". I do not understand this. Why /F/aspnetrelease/ is there more information on this topic?

Comment: @Matthias you certainly can. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It seems not work yet maybe I am doing something wrong. But would it be not the easiest thing to try to install the version on which the repository was tested with? Something with dnvm install but I do not know how I must specify the version. It does not find it.

Comment: @Matthias pointing to a specific CI build in a global.json is a bad practice. Why would you want that specific version? I don't think it's possible to install previous CI versions from MyGet.

Comment: When source code has been tested and runs against a certain build of DNX I want to test it again to it before trying different versions. I just cannot compile that middleware of the given repository so far. Basically this is my real problem. In case that is not possible because the build is not available. That changes the situation. I then need to ask how to build it at all (today). Because there were breaking changes several times during dnx development.

Comment: By today mean it not literally but with the available version.

Comment: @Matthias why don't you just use a stable build? Like beta7, or beta8 which just got released?

Comment: I updated to the stable beta 8 and still got errors. I posted an issue in the original Github repository: https://github.com/Kukkimonsuta/Odachi/issues/4

Comment: Thanks to the awesome fast developer. It can be built in beta 8 now:)

Comment: @Matthias I noticed, nice to hear!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use beta8 bits then you have to run `dnvm upgrade -u` (-u means unstable; aka dev feed)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It seems it did not download the beta 8. Could you check my update (see last paragraph of my question)