# Trying to follow updated MVC tutorial for MVC 6 using VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In the ["adding a model" section](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/getting-started/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html) of the tutorial, the instructions are:

> Run the following commands in the command prompt:

```
dnu restore
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -p
dnx ef migrations add Initial
dnx ef database update
```

When executing `dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-final -p` I get an error of type `Invoke-Command : Cannot find dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-final`. So I find two possible solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944313/dnx-sdk-version-dnx-clr-win-x86-1-0-0-beta8-15530-failed-to-install) post:

**Solution #1:**

```
SET DNX_FEED=https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetrelease/
dnvm upgrade
```

**Solution #2:**

> If you want to use beta8 bits then you have to run "dnvm upgrade -u" (-u means unstable; aka dev feed)

...but both solutions get my console stuck in this state (for more than an hour):

```
Downloading dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc2-16308 from https://www.myget.org/F/aspnetvnext/api/v2

 Installing runtime
    Unpacking runtime
```

Any way to circumvent these problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the dnx changed in the latest version of ASP.NET 5.
It is now called `1.0.0-rc1-update1`.

You can find out the version name inside `global.json` file.